# Porting Wii and/or PSOne Games to OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, porting, wii

I have been asked to investigate porting Wii games and some (Sony) PSOne games to OpenGL ES (can you guess what platform?).

I have never undertaken a game port like this before (and will be hiring someone to do it) but I'd like to understand the process.

1. Does the Wii use OpenGL? If not what does it use and how easy is it to port to OpenGL / OpenGL ES?
2. Are there any resources/books/blogs that will help me in understanding the process?
3. Will my company have to become an official Wii developer? If so where do I start that process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porting from the Wii or the PSOne is a complex and involved task that can be broken down into multiple separate engineering efforts working in parallel to produce a working end product.  The best possible thing you can do before moving to the target hardware is to compartmentalize all of the non-portable code while ensuring that the game continues to run as expected.  When you commit to moving to the new platform, your effort switches to reimplementing the non-portable compartmentalized parts.

So, to answer your question, yes, you will need to become or work with a Sony and Nintendo licensed developer in order to take this approach.  In the case of Sony, I don't even know if they offer a PSOne development program anymore which presents issues.  Your Sony account rep can help clarify.

The major subsystems that are likely to be the focus of your porting effort are:

1. **Rendering**  Graphics code contains fundamental assumptions about the hardware it is being run on in order to perform optimally.  API-level compatibility is superficial compatibility and does not get you as much as you may hope it does.  Plan on finding the entry point to the renderer and determining what data you need to render a scene and rewriting all the render code from there for your target hardware.
2. **Game Saving** Game state serialization and archival will need to be separated out.  Older games often fwrite() structs with #pragma packed fields.  Is that still going to work for you?
3. **Networking** Wii games write to high level services that are unavailable on your target hardware.  At the low level, sockets are still sockets.  What network services do your Wii games rely on?
4. **Controls** From where you are coming from to where you are going, anything short of a full redesign or reimagining of input will result in poor reviews of the software.
5. **Memory Management** Console games often make fundamental assumptions about the rate the system software returns memory from the heap, how much fragmentation it will cause and the duration the game needs to operate under these conditions.  These memory management assumptions are obsolete on the new platform.  It is wise to write your own memory manager that provides a cushion from the operating system.  Also, console games compiled for release are stripped of most error handling and don't gracefully handle running out of memory-- just a heads up.
6. **Content** Your bottleneck will be system memory.  Can you fit the necessary assets into memory?  With textures, you can reduce mip where necessary and with graphics hardware timing, you can pull in the far clipping plane.  With assets resident in memory, you may need a technical artist to go through and reduce the face density of your models or an animation programmer to implement a more size-friendly animation codec.  This is very game specific.

You also run into the standard set of problems with things like bit compatibility (though the Wii and PSOne are both 32-bit), compiler idiosyncrasies, build script incompatibilities and proprietary compiler extensions.

Games are relatively challenging to test.  A good rule of thumb is you want to have enough testers on your team to run through the game in a maximum of two days, covering all major aspects of play.  In games that take a long time to beat (RPGs with 30+ hours of gameplay), your testing team needs to be quite large to offer full coverage.  Because you are just doing a port, you can come up with a testing plan that maximizes coverage of your new code without having a testing team punch every wall in your game to make sure it (still) has clipping.  The game shipped once.

Becoming a licensed developer requires you to apply.  The turnaround time, from experience, is not good.  Generally speaking, priority is given to studios with shipped titles and organized offices with reasonably good security and the ability to buy the (relatively) expensive development kits.  You may be better off working with a licensed developer if you do not meet these criteria.

Console and game development is challenging for people already experienced in it.  There is no book that covers it all.  My recommendation is to attempt to recruit an expert who has experience shipping titles in a position of systems or engine programmer.  What types of programmers and skillsets exist in games is a whole different question for Stack, though.

Answer (score 3):

Games consoles don't use OpenGL but their own, custom libraries. The main reason is that they are pretty slow and have little RAM. So you need to squeeze out every drop of performance you can get. And that means: Custom code. Usually, you get a framework with the developer kit which gets you started and then, you build your code from that. Eventually, you'll start replacing parts from the developer kit with your own special code to get all the speed and special effects you need.

There is a reason why PSOne games are so ugly on the PS3 despite the fact that the developers have access to the sources: Revenue just doesn't justify to touch the code.

Which is one reason why game development is so expensive: Every game is (more or less) a completely new product. Sometimes, game companies can reuse a bit of code from the last version but more often than not, they have to develop everything again. They also don't talk much with each other.

In recent years, kits have become more complex and powerful and you can get complete game engines (with all kinds of effects and 3D support) but each engine is a completely different kind of beast, so you can't even copy code from engine A to B.

Today, media content (video, audio and render sequences) are so expensive that the actual game engine is often a minor detail, so this isn't going to change any time soon.

Net result: If you want to port a game, write an emulator for the hardware (which is usually pretty simple *and* allows you to run all kinds of games).

[EDIT] To develop software for the Wii, see here: http://www.warioworld.com/

For a Wii emulator, see http://wiiemulator.net/

Comment: This is simultaneously useful (+1) and useless (-1) but +1 for effort, thanks.

Comment: It's useful but disappointing ;) I've added a link where you read up on becoming an official Wii developer. But I guess that among the rules on the contract you will find "must not build Wii emulator".

Comment: Actually you wan reuse quite a bit of the code across platforms with the right architecture (info from a friend at a major game studio), but at the end of the day your actual capabilities are limited by the platform.  Often, re-creating artwork (3D models and textures) is the largest hurdle.  For some releases they will use the least common denominator in terms of artwork quality just because reworking and retesting artwork takes time, and they push schedules to the limit as it is.

Comment: One would assume that you'd create the textures at the highest possible quality and then scale them down for the less powerful consoles but there are probably so many details where this breaks that it doesn't happen in reality.

Answer (score 3):

I ported a couple of games, when I was a new game programmer, from working with one version of our engine to a newer version (where backwards compatibility was neither ignored nor pursued).  Even copying (and possibly renaming) the files and placing them in a home in the new project was a bit of work.  Following that, the procedure was:

- recompile
- fix many of the hundreds of errors [in many places, with the same error occurring over and over again]

and

- "wire up" calls from the new game engine to the appropriate calls in the old code
- "wire up" function calls from the old code into the new game engine
- deal with other oddities (ex. in the old game engine, the 2d game would "swizzle"  textures itself; in the new version, the engine did it (on specific platforms))
- and, while I don't recall this clearly, it was probably mixed in with a bunch of `#ifdef`fing out portions of code so the thing would actually compile, and possibly creating function stubs to be filled in later.

As I recall, it was three or four days until I had something that compiled.  (But, it did help when we ported other games from the old version to the new one!)

The magnitude of the task will come down to what the code you are getting is like.  If it has generic 3D calls that you can intercept -- add a thunking layer to -- then you are in business.  It depends on the level of abstraction in the code.  If it is well-behaved and has things like "RenderModel" and "RenderWorld" calls, you can replace those functions, and even the structures that they work with.  If drawing is occurring all over the place, and calls are more like "Draw Polygon" and "Draw Line" or "Draw using this highly optimised data structure", then you are likely in for a long slog.

You shouldn't need a Wii dev kit.  Sometimes it is nice to verify that the code you are given does indeed compile in the original environment (and matches the shipping code!), but sometimes you can just take it on faith and make it work in its new environment.

Lastly, I don't think the Wii uses OpenGL, and I really don't know where to point you for further help.

Answer (score 1):

What you may want to do is to start with designing the architecture of the game, write up a detailed specification for what the new game is like.

Once you have this, since you will be rewriting the code, you may find that some of the business logic that doesn't deal with the console can be ported over.  But, anything dealing with I/O, user interaction or graphics/sounds will be rewritten, so you might as well do that from scratch.

A specification is very important, to make certain that you know how the current game is working so that the new port will give the same user experience, if that is what is desired.

You may want to keep the same bugs, if that is part of the experience, as, if I know that in the Wii I can jump down and bounce off the wall to safely land, then if I can't do that in the new version then that may be bothersome.

Answer (score 1):

Well porting a PS1 game to an iPhone would be quite a task they work in very different ways.  I'm sure its doable but it will be a LOT of work to replace all the fixed point maths and lack of Z-Buffer based rendering to a real graphics chip.

Wii would be a lot easier.   The Wii API is very similar to OpenGL.  However the Wii has some very nice fixed function features that just are not available on any other GL based platform.  Should be doable, though ...

I'm not really sure I can say anything more than that.  Have signed far too many NDAs over the years to be 100% sure of what I can and cannot say ;)

Still if you want to hire someone to do some porting work and are prepared to supply the required hardware then I might be free ;)